# Hide the Title bar and frame in SDL window

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl

i am modifying the source present [here](http://eris.liralab.it/iCub/main/dox/html/iCub__Sim_8cpp_source.html) . To disable the title bar and frame on the SDL window , I embeded the SDL_NOFRAME flag , in both the SDL_setvideomode function present in source

```
SDL_SetVideoMode(h,w,32,SDL_OPENGL | SDL_RESIZABLE | SDL_NOFRAME);
```

compiled again, but i still can see the title bar and the frame .

Comment: What is the operating system you are using?

Comment: SDL_NOFRAME is not guaranteed to succeed everywhere. Check the `flags` member of the returned surface.

Comment: @Leonel I am using Ubuntu 11.10 .

Comment: @jrok How to check the flags member ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe SDL_RESIZABLE requires the frame to be present for the window to be resizable, so you have provided conflicting arguments try a non resizable window.

Comment: I removed the SDL_RESIZABLE flag , now also the window is visible and is re-sizable .Strange.

Comment: You could always recreate the window if you want to toggle like this, although I don't know how this affects stuff like OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

from wiki

SDL_NOFRAME

**If possible**, SDL_NOFRAME causes SDL to create a window with no title bar or frame decoration.